# creating bell graph using js function or jQ plugin

Tags: jquery, graph, charts

I need a js function or jQ plugin for creating following type bell graph. If anyone know the link pls help me[image]

Answer (score 3):

Raphaël is a small JS library for generating vector based images which may be what you need. You can find it at http://raphaeljs.com/.

Comment: Sorry, I need one bell graph curve  and need to fill multiple colours inside graph. any luck ?